# Page number in "list of tables"

Tags: formatting

This isn't an ideal SE site to ask this question, but I haven't found a better one. Please suggest one if you feel different.

In a "list of tables", what is the accepted convention for the page number for tables that flow over more than one page?

Word and Latex appear to default to the page on which the caption begins, but when the caption is below the table, it doesn't feel natural to me.

Comment: There is a Writing and a Latex exchange that might be helpful to you.

Comment: @scrappedcola: The [TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) is more about how to achieve a particular goal with LaTeX or similar formats. I'm not convinced questions on what those goals might be are on-topic there.

Comment: I don't know about "accepted convention" but the two reasonable solutions to me would be to either use the first page number or the page range.

Comment: IMO the page number should be that of the first page of the table. A slightly different way to solve this: I've always been taught to put captions *above* tables (and below figures).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying for precision in the information that is provided to a reader in this list, the ideal solution would be to list the whole page range that is spanned by the table.

If that is not possible, then I think that it would be appropriate to think about this with the same logic that is used for pointers to other multi-page items such as chapter: point to the beginning, since that's where the reader should be starting.

Better yet, however, if you have to have a multi-page table, why not remove it from the "flow" of the text entirely and turn it into an appendix or a supplementary document?